# Show shell variable in window opener

Tags: bash, shell

This is my case, i have a bash script which contains some variable `$var` and it also generates a HTML document, in the HTML code(which is also in my script) i have:

```
<a href=\"???\" onclick=\"window.open('???', 'newwindow', 'width=500, height=500'); return false;\">Click</a>
```

I need to open a new window after clicking and show my `$var` on that window.

How is that possible and what should i use or put where i have interrogation marks?

PS: I have no problem accessing variables from my script on my navigator, no client server issues.

Comment: Do you trust the source of that variable? Escaping against javascript-injection attacks would make this much harder.

Comment: it is a variable generated by my script

Comment: ...yes; the point I'm making is that it's important to consider **how** your script generates it, based on what data, and thus whether its range of possible contents is adequately constrained.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you simply want this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"var win=window.open('about:blank', 'newwindow', 'width=500, height=500'); win.document.writeln('$var'); return false;\">Click</a>"
```

Comment: i tried this and my `$var` is shown on the title of the window not inside the window itself

Comment: so `show my $var on that window` was supposed to be interpreted as `show my $var in that window`!